# regex for optional characters

Tags: java, regex

I am using the following regex:

```
^([W|w][P|p]|[0-9]){8}$
```

The above regex accepts `wp1234567` (`wp`+7 digits) also. Whereas expected: `WP`+6digit or `wp`+6digit or only 8 digit

For example:

```
WP123456
wp126456
64535353
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that `[W|w]` matches `W`, `w` and `|`, since `|` inside a character class loses its special meaning of an alternation operator. Also, by setting the grouping `(...)` around `[W|w][P|p]|[0-9]` you match 8 occurrences of *the whole sequences of `WP` *or* digits.

You should set the correct value in the limited quantifier and remove grouping and use alternation to allow either `wp`+6 digits or just 8 digits:

```
^(?:[Ww][Pp][0-9]{6}|[0-9]{8})$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bE3oR9/2)

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string (not necessary if you check the whole string with `String#matches()`)
- `(?:[Ww][Pp][0-9]{6}|[0-9]{8})` - 2 alternatives:

  - `[Ww][Pp][0-9]{6}` - `W` or `w` followed with `P` or `p` followed with 6 digits
  - `|` - or...
  - `[0-9]{8}` - exactly 8 digits
- `$` - end of string

**Other scenarios (just in case):**

If you need to match strings consisting of 7 or 8 digits, you need to replace `{8}` limited quantifier with `{7,8}`:

```
^(?:[Ww][Pp][0-9]{6}|[0-9]{7,8})$
```

And in case you do not want to match `Wp123456` or `wP123456`, use one more alternation in the beginning:

```
^(?:(?:WP|wp)[0-9]{6}|[0-9]{8})$
```